# Setting ACL for 2 million files/folder via WINDOWS API

Tags: c++, windows, security, acl

I am trying to set permission on 2 million files/folder on Windows using its APIs.  These are the APIs I am using:

1. GetNamedSecurityInfo
2. SetEntriesInACL
3. SetNamedSecurityInfo

I have created an `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` structure where the ACE flag is set to `NO_PROPAGATE_INHERIT_ACE`. I have created a MAP for all files/folder and running `SetNamedSecurityInfo()` in a `for` loop. My intention is to set each and every file/folder one by one. But somehow, when a folder is assigned by this function to set the permission, it starts setting its subfolders' permission as well. But according to what I read on MSDN, that if `NO_PROPAGATE_INHERIT_ACE` is set, `CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE` and    `OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE` is removed, therefore ACE propagation to child objects does not happen.

example code:

```
GetNamedSecurityInfo((char*)path.c_str(). SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &pOldACL, NULL, $psSD);

SertEntriesInACL(SID_COUNT, ea, pOldACL, &PNewACL);

for (map<_int64, CString>::iterator it=MyMap.begin(); it!= MyMap.end();++it)
{
    SetNamedSecurityInfo((char*)path.c_str(), ObjectType, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, pDacl, NULL);
}
```

The problem is once `SetNamedSecurityInfo()` finds a directory in the list, it starts propagating the ACE to child objects, and hence it takes time.

What flag should I use so that this propagation does not take place?

Comment: On a side note: `(char*)path.c_str()` looks very suspicious. What is `path` declared as exactly? If it is `std::string` or `CString`, the type-cast is unnecessary. If it is `std::wstring`, the type-cast is wrong.  Also, your `for` loop is ignoring the `it` iterator, which I presume contains paths that you want to call `(Get|Set)NamedSecurityInfo()` for.

Comment: use `SetKernelObjectSecurity` - it set DACL exactly how passed to, and much more faster if compare with `SetNamedSecurityInfo`